# Is it possible to install Android 5.0 Lollipop on Nokia Lumia 2520?

Tags: android, tablet, lumia

There seems to be multiple guides under different title on the matter.

Can anyone verify if this is indeed possible? It seems so fishy.

http://www.icqandroid.org/tutorial/nokia-lumia-2520.html

http://www.androidgamers.org/

Comment: I think there would be more hype and concrete (i.e. noteworthy) links if it were possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No its not there yet. The link which you mentioned contains survey links and most of such links turn out to be false.

Answer (score 0):

No, even here in Nokia Land, Finland no one knows that it could be done.. i wish someone will soon resolve it because we lumia owners will not have possibility to upgrade to Win 10 :(